# Is this permutation-sum problem NP-complete?

Tags: np-hardness, time-complexity, np-complete

A new, tighter tardiness bound has been found for global Earliest-Deadline-First scheduling of jobs on symmetric multiprocessors. But this bound seems to be particularly hard to compute. In particular, we were not able either to find a polynomial-time algorithm to compute this bound, or to prove that the problem is NP-hard. In this respect, a sufficient condition for the problem to be NP-hard, is that the following sub-problem is NP-complete.

Given:

- a set $\tau$ of $N$ pairs $(C_i, U_i) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$, with
  $C_i > 0$ and $0 < U_i \le 1$ for all
  $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$,
- the smallest natural number $M$ such that
  $\sum_{i=1}^{N} U_i \le M$ (which implies $M \le N$, because
  $U_i \le 1$),
- an integer $M'$ with $1 \le M' \le M$,
- a strictly positive value $b \in \mathbb{Q}$;

does a permutation
$\tau' = ( (C_{i_1},U_{i_1}), (C_{i_2},U_{i_2}), \ldots,
(C_{i_{M'-1}}, U_{i_{M'-1}}))$
of $M' - 1$ pairs in $\tau$ exist, such that
$$
  \sum_{g = 1}^{M'-1}\frac{C_{i_g}}{M - \sum_{v=1}^{g-1}U_{i_v}} \ge b
  \quad ?
 $$

Any suggestion for proving that this is problem is NP-hard, or, on the other hand, for finding a way to solve the problem in polynomial time?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Actually, I posted this question on Math Stackexchange first. After that, Mike Haskell kindly suggested me to post it also on cstheory and math overflow, to have more chances to get a good answer. But, most certainly, I had to wait for a few days between each cross-post. I am sorry for not waiting. If it is better to remove the question for now, I will do it.

Comment: As a courtesy, one should always leave notes that one has cross-posted, with links to all the relevant sites where the post appears. I see this has been done at this site in the body of the question.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Cross-posting violates site rules. Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: @usul I have removed the question from Mathematics, so it should appear only here now. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I am closing this one, so we don't have multiple copies of the same question.